# SQL Subquery to display Percent of Total

Tags: sql

I'm trying to obtain a table that will have the following 3 column

1. Geographical Area (FSA)
2. Sales (GRS_CAD)
3. Percent of total (Percent of Total), which is simply the value in column 2 divided by the sum of all values in column 2.

I have 2 constraints since I will be using the query in a Tableau dashboard:

- Cannot declare a variable
- Cannot create a temporary table

I'm fairly new at this, and I tried nesting queries. The result I obtain almost "looks" right, but I believe that the denominator for my third column changes for each row, and it shouldn't. Also, when I only run the sub-query for the denominator, I get the right number so I am guessing it might have something to do with the order in which the queries are executed.

Can you help?

```
SELECT  
SubTable.FSA 
, SubTable.GRS_CAD 
, SubTable.GRS_CAD/

        (
        SELECT sum(RPTOP.totaladjrevenue_onehr)

        FROM  csn_order.dbo.tblorderproduct OP (nolock)
        JOIN csn_report.dbo.rptorderproduct RPTOP (nolock) on OP.opid = RPTOP.opid
        JOIN csn_order.dbo.tblplstate PLSTATE (nolock) on OP.oprestid = PLSTATE.StID

        WHERE RPTOP.OrderSourceStoreID=446 
        AND RPTOP.Cancelled=0 
        AND RPTOP.OrCompleteDate > '2018-01-01' 
        AND PLSTATE.StID>=55 
        AND PLSTATE.StID<=67
        ) as 'Percent of total GRS'

FROM

    (SELECT 
         FSA = LEFT(A.oprepostalcode,3)
         , sum(B.totaladjrevenue_onehr) GRS_CAD
    FROM csn_order.dbo.tblorderproduct A (nolock)
        JOIN csn_report.dbo.rptorderproduct B (nolock) on A.opid = B.opid
        JOIN csn_order.dbo.tblplstate C (nolock) on A.oprestid = C.StID
    WHERE B.Ordersourcestoreid = 446
        AND B.cancelled = 0
        AND B.OrCompleteDate > '2018-01-01'
        AND C.StID >= 55 
        AND C.StID<=67
    GROUP BY LEFT(A.oprepostalcode,3))
 as SubTable
```

Comment: is this TSQL  qry ?

Comment: I think your problem could be easily resolved by using Group by. If not, try using Count() Over() to determine your denominator

Comment: Make it easy to help you - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: You can use temporary tables in Tableau, you just have to create them in the "Initial sql" section and query from them using custom sql

Answer (score 0):

You can always transform queries like yours with this technique. This will always create an `efficient SQL statement` as each select statement is not executed per row.

1. Move your select statement to the **from** clause.
2. Give your select statement and desired column a name.

   ```
   SELECT SubTable.FSA,
          SubTable.GRS_CAD,
          SubTable.GRS_CAD / PercentTotalOFGRS.TempName
   FROM
   (
       SELECT FSA = LEFT(A.oprepostalcode, 3),
              SUM(B.totaladjrevenue_onehr) GRS_CAD
       FROM csn_order.dbo.tblorderproduct A (NOLOCK)
           JOIN csn_report.dbo.rptorderproduct B (NOLOCK)
               ON A.opid = B.opid
           JOIN csn_order.dbo.tblplstate C (NOLOCK)
               ON A.oprestid = C.StID
       WHERE B.Ordersourcestoreid = 446
             AND B.cancelled = 0
             AND B.OrCompleteDate > '2018-01-01'
             AND C.StID >= 55
             AND C.StID <= 67
       GROUP BY LEFT(A.oprepostalcode, 3)
   ) AS SubTable ,
   (
       SELECT SUM(RPTOP.totaladjrevenue_onehr) AS TempName
       FROM csn_order.dbo.tblorderproduct OP (NOLOCK)
           JOIN csn_report.dbo.rptorderproduct RPTOP (NOLOCK)
               ON OP.opid = RPTOP.opid
           JOIN csn_order.dbo.tblplstate PLSTATE (NOLOCK)
               ON OP.oprestid = PLSTATE.StID
       WHERE RPTOP.OrderSourceStoreID = 446
             AND RPTOP.Cancelled = 0
             AND RPTOP.OrCompleteDate > '2018-01-01'
             AND PLSTATE.StID >= 55
             AND PLSTATE.StID <= 67
   ) AS PercentTotalOFGRS;
   ```